# Can't play video url using android Webview

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming

video cannot be played using webview android studio, but when unmute it can be played

```
public class Sila3bFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);

        final WebView mWb = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.wv_Tab2);
        mWb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/sila3/pagemaknaC.html");
        mWb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        return mView;
    }
}
```

Comment: video file having .html file extension ?

Answer (score 0):

```
     WebSettings settings = mWb.getSettings();
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        mWb.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "assets read string data", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```